Struggling with Google Earth Engine to download temperature data from ERA5 that corresponds to my reference dataset
This is what my reference dataset looks like, I want to get monthly min, max and mean temperatures for each of the site-years. I split each site year into 12 months but I don't know if that is necessary:
long   Lat  year date      
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <date>    
1 -85.4  42.4  2007 2007-01-01
2 -85.4  42.4  2007 2007-02-01
3 -85.4  42.4  2007 2007-03-01
4 -85.4  42.4  2007 2007-04-01
5 -85.4  42.4  2007 2007-05-01
6 -85.4  42.4  2007 2007-06-01

When I use the following code to extract temperature data from ERA5 my coordinates aren't recognized and it outputs empty geometries:
// Load the CSV file as a FeatureCollection

var csvData = ee.FeatureCollection('projects/ee-/df_monthly');

 

// Print to verify the CSV data is loaded

print(csvData, 'CSV Data:');

Map.addLayer(csvData, null, 'sites');

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//define vars

//var bbox = ee.Geometry.Rectangle({coords:[114.96256, -30.40689, 115.18764,-30.02759],geodesic:false});

var from = ee.Date('1985-01-01');

var to = ee.Date('2021-12-12');

///////////////get data

// Load the ERA5 Monthly dataset

var era5 = ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/MONTHLY_AGGR").filterDate(from, to);

// get temperature and precipitation

var forcing = era5.select(['temperature_2m','total_precipitation_sum']);

print(forcing);

 

///extract and export

 

var values = forcing.map(function(image) {

 

  return image.reduceRegions({

     collection: csvData,

     reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),

     crs:'EPSG:4326',

     tileScale: 16,

     scale: 10000

  }).map(function(f){

        return f.set('date', image.get('system:index'));

    });

}).flatten();

 

/// check extraction

print(values.limit(10),'values');

 

 

Export.table.toDrive({

  collection: values,

  description: 'Enriched_CSV_Data',

  fileFormat: 'CSV'

});

Hope I provided enough info.

I slightly changed and imported your CSV file as an asset which looks like this.


The rest of the code pretty much the same. Only path for FeatureCollection and column names.
// Load the CSV file as a FeatureCollection
var csvData = ee.FeatureCollection('projects/ee-xxx/assets/test');

// Print to verify the CSV data is loaded
print(csvData, 'CSV Data:');

// Convert CSV data to features with geometries
var sites = csvData.map(function(feature) {
  var lon = feature.get('long');
  var lat = feature.get('lat');
  var geom = ee.Geometry.Point([lon, lat]);
  return feature.setGeometry(geom);
});

Map.addLayer(sites, {color: 'red'}, 'Sites');

// Define time range
var from = ee.Date('1985-01-01');
var to = ee.Date('2021-12-12');

// Load the ERA5 Monthly dataset
var era5 = ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/MONTHLY_AGGR").filterDate(from, to);

// Get temperature and precipitation
var forcing = era5.select(['temperature_2m', 'total_precipitation_sum']);
print(forcing);

// Extract and export
var values = forcing.map(function(image) {
  return image.reduceRegions({
    collection: sites,
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    crs: 'EPSG:4326',
    scale: 10000
  }).map(function(f) {
    return f.set('date', image.get('system:index'));
  });
}).flatten();

// Check extraction
print(values.limit(10), 'Values');

// Export to Drive
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: values,
  description: 'Enriched_CSV_Data',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});

The results looks good I guess

